# SQL (PostgreSQL) unique value between groups

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, unique-index

I have a table with columns val_A, val_B. Having a requirement that I can do only inserts (no updates/deletes and i would like to avoid triggers and store procedures).

How I can achieve such a requirement that value of column val_A must be unique but **not** for entire table but only of groups based on val_B. In other words, I can have many entries with val_A = 1 for val_B = 1, but in that case i cannot have val_A = 1 with val_B != 1;

For Example:

```
+-------+-------+---------------------+
| val_A | val_B |       Comment       |
+-------+-------+---------------------+
|     1 |     1 |                     |
|     2 |     1 |                     |
|     1 |     1 | This is Allowed     |
|     1 |     2 | This is not allowed |
+-------+-------+---------------------+
```

**EDIT #1**
The solution I'm looking for should work for current inserts.
I was trying something similar to [Davide Anghileri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14612449/davide-anghileri) response but that failed in concurrent insert scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the checking condition in a WHERE clause. Here an example:

```
INSERT INTO table_name(val_A, val_B)
SELECT 1, 2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE val_A=1 AND val_B!=2)
```

You can take the numbers to insert (e.g. 1, 2) from another table if you want. Also the number in the Where clause should be set to the other table:

```
 val_A=other_table.val_A AND val_B!=other_table.val_B
```

With this condition you can insert 1,1 but not 1,2 since you already have a record with same val_A and different val_B.

Comment: Thank you, please see my original post EDIT #1

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky but you can create a unique index on an expression -- and use the fact that Postgres allows `NULL` values to be repeated in a unique index.

So:

```
create unique index unq_t_val_a_val_b on
    (case when val_a <> val_b then least(val_a, val_b) end,
     case when val_a <> val_b then greatest(val_a, val_b) end
    );
```

When the values are *different*, then `least()` and `greatest()` creates an index with two keys with the values in order.  When the values are the same, the keys are `NULL` so they are not really part of the unique index.

You can also do this with filtering:

```
create unique index unq_t_val_a_val_b on
    (least(val_a, val_b), greatest(val_a, val_b))
    where val_a <> val_b;
```

Comment: I don't think this answers OP.  Their example was poorly written.  Its not that A must = B its that B multiple rows can have the same A, B pair, but no rows with A, B with a different B. I ```+-------+-------+---------------------+
| val_A | val_B |       Comment       |
+-------+-------+---------------------+
|     1 |     3 |                     |
|     2 |     1 |                     |
|     1 |     3 | This is Allowed     |
|     1 |     2 | This is not allowed |
+-------+-------+---------------------+```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a unique filtering index:

```
create unique index myidx 
    on mytable(val_a)
    where (val_b is distinct from 1)
```

This allows duplicates in `val_a` only on rows where `val_b` has value `1`.

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot fix on value 1 only. This must be a generic solution.